# Adding custom claims to ClaimsPrincipal when using AddAzureADB2C in MVC Core App

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c, claims

When authentication using azure AzureADB2C I would like to add custom claims which are managed in the portal to the Claims Principle

```
current code in start up 
   services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureADB2C(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options));
```

I was thinking it should work something like this but on token validated is never hit

```
 services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureADB2C(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options))
                .AddJwtBearer(o =>
                    {
                        o.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                                       {
                                           OnTokenValidated = async ctx =>
                                               {
                                                       var claims = new List<Claim> { new Claim("ConfidentialAccess", "true") };
                                                       var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);
                                                       ctx.Principal.AddIdentity(appIdentity);
                                               }
                                       };
                    });
```

Answer (score 11):

In general, we would use OpenIdConnect middleware for AAD authentication. And you could use the following code lines for adding custom claim(s).

```
//OpenIdConnectOptions
options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
{
    OnTokenValidated = context =>
    {   
        var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identity;
        //add your custom claims here
        claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("test", "helloworld!!!"));

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
};
```

If you are using [AzureADB2CAuthenticationBuilderExtensions.AddAzureADB2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.azureadb2cauthenticationbuilderextensions.addazureadb2c?view=aspnetcore-2.1) by installing package [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureADB2C.UI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureADB2C.UI), I assumed that there is no approach for you to set [OpenIdConnectEvents.OnTokenValidated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect.openidconnectevents.ontokenvalidated?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

From [AzureAdB2CAuthenticationBuilderExtensions.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/AADIntegration/blob/28e81276582af23f4c616d9db900664960682074/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureADB2C.UI/AzureAdB2CAuthenticationBuilderExtensions.cs), you could find the code line under `AddAzureADB2C` method for instantiating `OpenIdConnectOptions`.

```
builder.Services.TryAddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>, OpenIdConnectOptionsConfiguration>();
```

For [OpenIdConnectOptionsConfiguration.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/AADIntegration/blob/28e81276582af23f4c616d9db900664960682074/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI/OpenIdConnectOptionsConfiguration.cs), you could find that you have no chance to set `OpenIdConnectOptions.Events`.

Fortunately, here is a code sample which seperately defines [AzureAdB2COptions.cs](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp/blob/master/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet/AzureAdB2COptions.cs) and [OpenIdConnectOptionsSetup.cs](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp/blob/master/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet/OpenIdConnectOptionsSetup.cs). I assumed that you could follow my code snippet to modify the `Configure` method under [OpenIdConnectOptionsSetup.cs](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp/blob/master/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet/OpenIdConnectOptionsSetup.cs) to meet your requirement. Detailed tutorial you could follow [An ASP.NET Core web app with Azure AD B2C](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp).

Comment: In your code you make a copy of the `context.Principal.Identity` and then only add the claims to that `var claimsIdentity` copy. I don't understand why does the `context.Principal.Identity` end up containing the custom claims as well?