# ASP.NET Core MVC AzureAD run code after successful sign-in

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I'm using I have authentication with AzureAD set up using OpenID Connect with an ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC app. I want to be able to log info about the user right after a successful sign-in into the application.

In the code below, I use `options.Events.OnTicketReceived` event to add role claims from an external database to the Identity after they have successfully authenticated with AzureAD. However, my research tells me that the `OnTicketReceived` event is called right **before** the user is signed-in, that is, right before the local cookie is created and the user is authenticated with the app (Source: [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52727146/net-core-2-openid-connect-authentication-and-multiple-identities#comment98498256_52728380), [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42452250/12300287)). This would mean that the user hasn't been authenticated with the app yet, and I don't know if after the `OnTicketReceived` event the user is guaranteed to be authenticated.

All of this makes me wonder is it correct to log my "user signed in" message on the `OnTicketReceived` event or is there another way of doing it? I am also unsure if it is in Startup.cs that I should be logging this info.

Startup.cs > ConfigureServices method

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection Services)
{
    //https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/dec/12/easy-configuration-binding-in-aspnet-core-revisited
    IAppSettings config = new AppSettings();
    Configuration.Bind("AppSettings", config);

    Services.AddMvc();
    Services.AddSingleton(config);
    
    //bunch of service dependencies here...

    Services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    Services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddAzureAD(options =>
        {
            options.Instance = config.AzureAD.Instance;
            options.Domain = config.AzureAD.Domain;
            options.TenantId = config.AzureAD.TenantId; //TenantID is set to "organizations"
            options.ClientId = config.AzureAD.ClientId; //the ID of the registered app in AzureAD
            options.CallbackPath = config.AzureAD.CallbackPath;
        });

    Services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
    {
        options.UseTokenLifetime = false;
        options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/"; //Microsoft identity platform

        options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = true;
        options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuers = config.AzureAD.Organizations; //List<string> of allowed organizations
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49469979/azure-ad-b2c-user-identity-name-is-null-but-user-identity-m-instance-claims9
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54444747/user-identity-name-is-null-after-federated-azure-ad-login-with-aspnetcore-2-2
        options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier";

        //Code below is to add claims during login (we add roles from db): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51965665/adding-custom-claims-to-claimsprincipal-when-using-addazureadb2c-in-mvc-core-app
        //some discussion about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59564952/net-core-add-claim-after-azuerad-authentication
        //and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52727146/net-core-2-openid-connect-authentication-and-multiple-identities
        options.Events.OnTicketReceived = context =>
        {
            string userEmail = context.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
            //I get an instance of UserAccess service so I can check termination status and get the roles by email.
            IUserAccess userAccess = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IUserAccess>();
            
            bool terminated = userAccess.GetUserTerminationStatusByUserEmail(userEmail, config.ConnectionString);
            if (terminated == false)
            {
                ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identity;
                List<string> roles = userAccess.GetUserRolesByUserEmail(userEmail, config.ConnectionString);
                foreach (var role in roles)
                {
                    claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
                }
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
    });

    Services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(AzureADDefaults.CookieScheme, options =>
    {
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/UserAccess/NotAuthorized";
        options.LogoutPath = "/UserAccess/SignOut";
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(config.AzureAD.TimeoutInMinutes);
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    });
}
```

To sign-in and sign-out, I use the existing functions from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI` NuGet package, and call them in my views like this:

```
<!-- to sign out -->
<a asp-area="AzureAD" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignOut">Sign out</a>

<!-- to sign in -->
<a asp-area="AzureAD" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignIn">Sign in with Microsoft</a>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `Audit Log` to get the successful sign-ins?  `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/signIns?&$filter=status/errorCode eq 0`

Comment: @PamelaPeng I'm actually a newbie to logging and it was set up for us to be able to use logging methods like `_logger.LogInformation("message");` using NLog. Would you mind explaining or providing a resource on what that `Audit Log` and link is and how I could implement it into the app? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you said, `OnTicketReceived` is called when clicking on the sign-in button, but what you want are the successful sign-ins.

You will see the [sign-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-sign-ins) and [Audit logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-audit-logs) from Azure AD in the portal.

[image]

**Sign-ins** – Information about the usage of managed applications and user sign-in activities.

**Audit logs** - Audit logs provide system activity information about users and group management, managed applications, and directory activities.

So you don't need to add logs using NLog, the sign-in logs are automatically stored.
For more details about listing sign-ins, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/signin-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp).

**Code Sample:**

```
// Read application settings from appsettings.json (tenant ID, app ID, client secret, etc.)
AppSettings config = AppSettingsFile.ReadFromJsonFile();

// Initialize the client credential auth provider
IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(config.AppId)
    .WithTenantId(config.TenantId)
    .WithClientSecret(config.ClientSecret)
    .Build();
ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);

// Set up the Microsoft Graph service client with client credentials
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

// status/errorCode eq '0' means sign-in success
var signIns = await graphClient.AuditLogs.SignIns
    .Request()
    .Filter("status/errorCode eq '0'")
    .GetAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. The issue with sign-in logs being stored in AzureAD is that we would not have them in the database containing logs by NLog. It would be useful to also store the sign-ins in the database. Do you know a way to do that? Also, it's not guaranteed that we'll have permissions to view the Sign-ins page from within Azure Portal.

Comment: @Lukas Hi, lukas. You could get sign-ins using the code, or request the [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/signin-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/signIns`. Then store the response data to your database. There is no method to move the data into your database directly.